# i18next showing key names instead of translations after manual change of URL

Tags: reactjs

Just noticed whenever I manually change letter from capital to lowercase weird problem occurs changing my translations into key names so instead of "Hello World my friends" text what I see is header.helloworld
Its happening when i for example change `http://mypage/lbs` to `http://mypage/Lbs`. Notice the uppercase on "L".

Do you guys faced similar problem?